# Should we use url.connect() to make http request in android?

Tags: android

This is my code

```
    public static String makeHttpRequest(URL url)
       
    {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;

    String jsonResponse=null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200){
        InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        jsonResponse=readFromStream(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();}

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(urlConnection!=null)
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

I got the same jsonResponse when i am not using these lines

urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

urlConnection.connect();

after removing these lines. My code is :

```
 public static String makeHttpRequest(URL url)
 {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;
    String jsonResponse=null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        
        if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200){
        InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        jsonResponse=readFromStream(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();}

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(urlConnection!=null)
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }
    return jsonResponse;
}
```

Both will give the same json response.
which is better to use to make http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the line

```
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

creates an object

You are not always required to explicitly call the connect method to initiate the connection.

Operations that depend on being connected, like getInputStream, getOutputStream, etc, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

and the line

```
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
```

is not updating anything because the default method is GET
and the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod-java.lang.String-) for HttpUrlConnection#setRequestMethod hints at this:

> Set the method for the URL request, one of: GET POST HEAD OPTIONS PUT DELETE TRACE are legal, subject to protocol restrictions. The default method is GET.